# is there anyway i can auto generate architecture diagrams from a table of data

Tags: architecture, diagramming

i have a list of applications, services and databases in a text file.  the list includes which applications are consumers of which services and which services use which databases.  I would like to know if there is a tool that can take this data and generate an architecture diagram. i would like to output to be dynamic so when the text file is updated the diagram automatically updates

something similar to this tool (which doesn't seem available for the web)

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/msagl/default.aspx

Comment: If you can put it into an XML file it may be easier to format.

Comment: that is fine, i can convert to XML.. do you know a library to use once i have it in xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest equivalent I have seen is [**Graphviz**](http://www.graphviz.org/)

> Graphviz is open source graph visualization software.
>   It has several main graph layout programs. See the [gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) for some sample layouts.
>   It also has web and interactive graphical interfaces, and auxiliary tools, libraries, and language bindings.

[image: http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/cluster.png]

It has also several viewers, but not one in C#, as far as I know.